# Onclick functions in a while loop

Tags: javascript, loops, getelementbyid

I have x amount of elements with id "accordion_toggle__1" -> "accordion_toggle__x". I wanted to try to put an onclick function on each of them that would toggle the class "accordion__hidden" in the corresponding elements with ids "accordion__1" -> "accordion__x".

Here is the code that i tried to use:

```
let x=1;

while(!!document.getElementById("accordion_toggle__"+x)){
        document.getElementById("accordion_toggle__"+x).onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById("accordion__"+x).classList.toggle("accordion__hidden");
        }
        x++;
}
```

It doesn't seem to work. I think when e.g. I have 4 accordion_toggles, they all try to toggle the classlist of the unexisting "accordion__5". How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The `x` will always point to last(5) because that is `global var`.

For this case, just change to:

```
let x = 1;

while (!!document.getElementById("accordion_toggle__" + x)) {
    const n = x;
    document.getElementById("accordion_toggle__" + x).onclick =

    function() {
        document.getElementById("accordion__" + n).classList.toggle("accordion__hidden");
    }
    x++;
}
```